# Sparse Image matching in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, static-libraries, image-recognition

I am building an iOS app that, as a key feature, incorporates image matching. The problem is the images I need to recognize are small orienteering 10x10 plaques with simple large text on them. They can be quite reflective and will be outside(so the light conditions will be variable). Sample image

[image]

There will be up to 15 of these types of image in the pool and really all I need to detect is the text, in order to log where the user has been.

The problem I am facing is that with the image matching software I have tried, aurasma and slightly more successfully arlabs, they can't distinguish between them as they are primarily built to work with detailed images.

I need to accurately detect which plaque is being scanned and have considered using gps to refine the selection but the only reliable way I have found is to get the user to manually enter the text. One of the key attractions we have based the product around is being able to detect these images that are already in place and not have to set up any additional material.

Can anyone suggest a piece of software that would work(as is iOS friendly) or a method of detection that would be effective and interactive/pleasing for the user.

Sample environment:
http://www.orienteeringcoach.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/startfinishscp.jpeg

The environment can change substantially, basically anywhere a plaque could be positioned they are; fences, walls, and posts in either wooded or open areas, but overwhelmingly outdoors.

Comment: Do you have a couple of images of these plaques in their native environment, to give an idea of what we'd be looking to pick them out of? If you can't get a good solution to the more generalized image processing problem here, the people at http://dsp.stackexchange.com might be able to give you a hand with that part of it. They won't be able to describe a specific solution for iOS, though.

Comment: You probably need to pre-process the images to produce a high-contrast image -- throwing out all the gray scale info, and compensating for shadows, etc.  dsp.stackexchange.com may have some pointers.  (They're a hair more tolerant of "stupid" questions than is this board.)

Comment: My tactic so far was isolate the image and have a cropped inspection rect over layed on the camera. I would be expecting the user to align the image within the area.

Comment: Again, a sample image of what you'd imagine people would be looking at would be extremely helpful here. It might allow us to test against a few different image processing techniques.

Comment: Apologies I misunderstood the question. I have added a sample image.

Comment: Asking the user to keep the plaque in a certain region is certainly a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution that is working quite well. Im not fully optimized yet but I think its just tweaking filters, as ill explain later on.

Initially I tried to set up opencv but it was very time consuming and a steep learning curve but it did give me an idea. The key to my problem is really detecting the characters within the image and ignoring the background, which was basically just noise. OCR was designed exactly for this purpose.

I found the free library tesseract (https://github.com/ldiqual/tesseract-ios-lib) easy to use and with plenty of customizability. At first the results were very random but applying sharpening and monochromatic filter and a color invert worked well to clean up the text. Next a marked out a target area on the ui and used that to cut out the rectangle of image to process. The speed of processing is slow on large images and this cut it dramatically. The OCR filter allowed me to restrict allowable characters and as the plaques follow a standard configuration this narrowed down the accuracy.

So far its been successful with the grey background plaques but I havent found the correct filter for the red and white editions. My goal will be to add color detection and remove the need to feed in the data type.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an iOs programmer, but I will try to answer from an algorithmic point of view. Essentially, you have a detection problem ("Where is the plaque?") and a classification problem ("Which one is it?"). Asking the user to keep the plaque in a pre-defined region is certainly a good idea. This solves the detection problem, which is often harder to solve with limited resources than the classification problem.

For classification, I see two alternatives:

1. The classic "Computer Vision" route would be feature extraction  and classification. [Local Binary Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns) and [HOG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) are feature extractors known to be fast enough for mobile (the former more than the latter), and they are not too complicated to implement. Classifiers, however, are non-trivial, and you would probably have to search for an appropriate iOs library.
2. Alternatively, you could try to binarize the image, i.e. classify pixels as "plate" / white or "text" / black. Then you can use an error-tolerant similarity measure for comparing your binarized image with a binarized reference image of the plaque. The [chamfer distance measure](http://www.gavrila.net/Research/Chamfer_System/chamfer_system.html) is a good candidate. It essentially boils down to comparing the [distance transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform) of your two binarized images. This is more tolerant to misalignment than comparing binary images directly. The distance transforms of the reference images can be pre-computed and stored on the device.

Personally, I would try the second approach. A (non-mobile) prototype of the second approach is relatively easy to code and evaluate with a good image processing library (OpenCV, Matlab + Image Processing Toolbox, Python, etc).

Comment: Excellent response. My main problem is I dont have time to implement the matching algorithms, especially from zero experience. Im looking to find/purchase an complete solution that, unlike those i've used so far, works in my environment. You're point about binary classification gives me hope as the contrast for all the plaques is high. Thanks.